# How to pg_dump only data from a table in a PostgreSQL database and pipe it into an identical but differently-named table in another database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, psql, pg-dump

## Goal

I need to copy just the data from a table in one database into another table in another database. The table in the target database has the exact same schema *except that the name of the table is different*. The two databases are on the same machine.

## Problem

I can't find a way to pipe the data from `pg_dump` into a **differently named table** in the target database.

## What I've tried

Here's the command I would use if the tables were named the exact same:

`pg_dump -a -t <table_name> <source_db> | psql <target_db>`

But where would I be able to put the name of the target table in the target database?

#### Background info

The reason I'm doing this is because I'm building a Django web-app, and I've realized I really need to separate a bunch of the models I've created into different 'apps' within my Django project.

Comment: Do you need the `pg_dump`? You could specify the database with the `.using`-method and transfer them with Django.

Comment: Why pg_dump?  This should be easy with psql using COPY TO and COPY FROM.  How does pg_dump contributes anything but frustration.?

Comment: The only this is going to work is if you edit the dump file and do a find and replace on the table name.

Comment: @kerfuffle and @jjanes: I didn't realize there was an easier way than using `pg_dump` ; I definitely don't need the `pg_dump`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with `COPY`:

```bash
psql -d db1 -c 'COPY table_1 TO STDOUT' | psql -d db2 -c 'COPY table_2 FROM STDIN'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. What does the STDOUT and STDIN stand for?

Comment: Standard output and standard input, that is, the data get sent to the client or read from the client connection. See the `COPY` documentation.